# Is there an Array method for this?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

So I have an array of values

I have two values from this array of Int, Say A[a] and A[b]

I now want to search the array to see if it includes values that are >A[a] but < A[b]

I want to see if there are values in the array that are bigger than A[a] and less than A[b]

Say I have [1,3,5,6]

```
A[0] = 1
A[2] = 5
```

Now I want a method that would see if there is a value in this array between my two chosen values, i.e. I should get True because 3 is <5 and >1

How can I do this? Is there a method for this?

Comment: Yes, there's a method, one that you write. Please give it a go, and then come back with your code attempt and your specific questions if you're still stuck.

Comment: how do you want to _see_. Define _see_. Do you want to print them?

Comment: If the array is sorted then I think it is rather obvious.

Comment: While you are giving it a go, it may be worthwhile to consider whether the array can contain duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First lets restate your problem: Give two values, a and b, search an array arrayValues to see if there are any values that are between value a and value b (a < x < b).

```
    private boolean isPresent(int[] arrayValues, int a, int b) {
        boolean isPresent = false;
        int i = 0;
        while (!isPresent && i < arrayValues.length )) {
            isPresent = a < arrayValues[i] && arrayValues[i] < b;
                         i++;
        }

        return isPresent;
    }
```

Key computations are that we loop until we either find a value that meets the condition (and there are more elements in the array); and that we use the and operator (&&) to evaluate the two conditions that must be true.

Comment: 1+ for not giving just a solution but also a decent explanation to someone who has shown no effort.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way, but you may use the trick shown below.

Sort the array-->
make a list out of it-->
use lastindex and first index of the two numbers to decide.

See the code below:

```
    int[] ar = {1, 2, 4, 5, 2, 6};
    Arrays.sort(ar);
    List list = Arrays.asList(ar);

    int n1 = 4, n2 = 6; // Example of two numbers from array
    int indexDiff = list.lastIndexOf(n1) - list.indexOf(n2);
    if(indexDiff < -1){
        // there are items
    } else {
        // There are no items
    }
```

If you have many numbers to lookup than you need to sort and convert to list ONLY ONCE.

Comment: This is overkill for the task at hand. Do make your code parsimonious whenever possible ... it may be executed many many times.